# Why “--” turns into "-" when I deploy my markdown file using Hexo?

Tags: hexo

I am learning to use hexo to bolg. When I finish my job and deploy it.I find that all "--" turn into "-".What is the reason and how can I fix it.

Comment: What kind of '-'? Where are they? This needs more information.

Comment: Such as “git --version" or "npm install hexo-generator-index --save"  and they are after >

Comment: Is this relevant to Hexo, or the CLI you are using to manage Hexo?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know whether it is relevant to Hexo. But I am get this problem when I first deploy my word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The reason why in Hexo all double hyphens (`--`) generate into long dashes (`&mdash` or `—`) is because in [hexo-renderer-marked](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-renderer-marked) plugin option **smartypants** (Use "smart" typograhic punctuation for things like quotes and dashes) is **enabled** by default.
2. To disable it add in main Hexo `_config.yml`:

   ```
   marked:
     smartypants: false
   ```

   After that need to update text in your `*.md` file to regenerate output with new parameters by this plugin. Of course, `hexo clean && hexo g` or reload `hexo s` after that.